# Why React Rendered Pages are Ignored CSS Files

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a React app created using create-react-app which links to my CSS file as shown below in index.html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/site.css"></link>
```

The site.css is implemented below:

```
body {
  background-color: green;
  height:100%;
  width:100%; 
}
```

When my app is run it does not apply styles to the body. I can see the css file is being downloaded.

Comment: Have you tried to import your css into your component class? `import './site.css';`

Comment: Do I have to? Can't I just link it in the HTML file.

Comment: where your index.html and site.css files placed? Possibility of incorrect path of css in index.html. Check the path href=“../src/site.css” this seems creating an issue I guess

Comment: Do you even have a body tag ? you posted literally zero code.

Comment: You do not have to, but normally it is not the best way to style your application with react

Comment: `<link>` does not have a closing tag. Remove that.

Answer (score 1):

The `src` directory is not served with create-react-app. You either need to move your CSS file to the `public` directory or import it from one of your JavaScript files.

Internally everything is bundled using Webpack with loaders that understand stylesheets, so the simplest way to handle this is to remove the link tag from your `public/index.html` file and instead add the following import to your `src/index.js` file:

```
import "./site.css";
```

Alternatively, if you really need to link to the stylesheet from your html file, you can move it to `public/site.css` and change your link tag to reference it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site.css">
```